# i want to sort database according to the brand name's but its does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Controller

```cs
public ActionResult brand(int brand_Id = 0)
{
    var model = db.MVCs.Where(i => i.brand_Id == brand_Id);
    if (model == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

View

```cs
@model MVC3.Models.productDB
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "brand";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPageMaster.cshtml";
}
<h2>brand</h2>
@foreach(var item in Model.brand){
@Html.DisplayFor(i=>i.ProductName)}
```

Model

```cs
public class productDB
{   
    [Key]
    public int ID   {get;set;}
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProdactDetails { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public decimal? OffPrice { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public string image  { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Cat")]
    public int Cat_Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Cat_Id")]
    public virtual Cat Cat { get; set; }
    public string ProdactTitle { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "brand")]
    public int brand_Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("brand_Id")]
    public virtual Brand brand { get; set; }
}

public class productDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<productDB> MVCs { get; set; }
}
```

I want to sort database according to the brand name's but its does not work

error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[MVC3.Models.productDB]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MVC3.Models.productDB'.

Comment: in which function you return this view ?

Comment: The error is self explanatory. You passing a collection of `productDB` to a view that expects and single `productDB`

Comment: `var model = db.MVCs.Where(i => i.brand_Id == brand_Id).FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing your controller:

```
public ActionResult brand(int brand_Id = 0)
{
   var model = db.MVCs.Where(i => i.brand_Id == brand_Id).OrderBy(b => b.Brand.Brand_name).ToList();       
   if (model == null)
   {
       return HttpNotFound();
   }
   return View(model);
}
```

Also you can use [OrderByDescending()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx) .

More about `ToList()` : [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

When making your query you can simply call `.OrderBy(x => x.Brand.Brand_name)` on your collection of Products